# Allow outdated firefox extension to be enabled

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, firefox-extensions, pentadactyl

So I have a lovely extension called Pentadactyl. It's not maintained for every "major" Firefox release and thus may have an outdated version number somewhere. It does its job and frankly it's my problem if it doesn't.

In any case, I decided to update Firefox, upon restarting it tells me my extension isn't compatible and turns it off without my say. Then when I enter my extensions tab to enable it again there is not even the faintest glimpse of the possibility of doing so, even at my own risk.

The `about:config` doesn't seem to have the `checkCompatability` value anymore. Is there an elegant way to rectify this... lovely user experience Firefox has decided to provide for my safety?

I'm on FF  version 42.0. Unfortunately.

Comment: roll back to a previous version of Firefox.

Comment: @Ramhound It's a solution but it's not very nice since it has quite a few drawbacks. I could also hack the extensions version number, but it's really not great either and requires maintenance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to this would be to disable Add-on compatibility checks. This can be done by installing [Disable Add-on Compatibility Checks](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/checkcompatibility/)

`This add-on re-enables the functionality of extensions.checkCompatibility irrespective of the current application version and disables checking by default.`

This means that you will be able to install addons from any version of Firefox, but be careful, because you could break your Firefox installation. If you do, than hold the shift key while it is starting, and start it in safe mode.

Comment: Oh you amazing person, that's precisely what I searched for, now I can dump the ugly hack. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm still using FF41, but according to the reports on the [issue](https://github.com/5digits/dactyl/issues/95) at Github, the [Git version](https://github.com/5digits/dactyl) of Pentadactyl will work on 42 if you just alter the `install.rdf` file to change `em:maxVersion="41.*"` to `em:maxVersion="42.*"`.

You do this by unpacking the extension (it's just a zip file with a different extension/mimetype), changing the file, then repacking it (just zip it and change `.zip` to `.xpi`).

Comment: The discussion at the thread you linked to seems to indicate that Pentadactyl hasn't yet been completely tweaked and tested for 42, so this solution sort of makes users alpha testers.

Comment: @fixer1234: Well, the truth is, any Pentadactyl user on the latest FF is an alpha tester these days, but it seems to work okay. A few people have had trouble with the `help` command, but you can work around that if necessary (save the online help locally with `wget`, then redefine the help commands to access it). If anyone isn't happy troubleshooting a few issues, I'd probably advise them to use Vimperator for now.